# Feature or Extension to Jump over specific line from comment summary in Visual Studio or VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, comments

While working on different big .NET and Angular projects, I saw sometimes CSS or JS code becomes to lengthy in single file. At that time we have to scroll so much time find piece of code to modify. We usually give comment to differentiate CSS or JS section something like below.

```
/************************************************************/
/* Update By Contactor 1 :  30-4-2019 : New Style for Profile*/
/************************************************************/
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

but it still difficult find comment and react to particular section.

I have simple section, is it possible to reach to particular line in CSS or JS in Visual Studio or VS Code from Comment summary.

**Eg.**

```
/* Colors */
/* Pink:    #ed1849     */
/* Blue:    #006aad     */
/*Style for Profile Page*/
/*Style for Order Page*/
/*Style for Review Page*/
```

> like clicking on any above comment can scroll to particular section. I
>   know about **Ctrl + G** in built feature to jump to particular line,
>   but for it I need to aware about line number which is difficult to
>   track for large file

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a unique comment line preceding a code section, like

```
/* <Style for Profile> */
```

Then you can search for it from comment summary or use my [Favorite Documents](https://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension for VS to add these lines to favorites.